# Java JSP Servlet , Why my css dont work.Thanks

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a project written by jsp and servlet but It have a bug, my bootstap and some css file dont access EROR 404 and i also try change my link to access to css file but It dont work to me. This is my pic, THank you.
[image: This is my code]

[image: Display in Chrome]

Comment: Welcome to the site. At the moment your question is not giving a relevant excerpt of the affected code and a clear explanation about why that code is not working as you intend. Can you edit your question to include (just the relevant portion) of your code within your question rather than referring to an image of the code? (The image showing the rendered result in Chrome is fine, as this does require a graphical display.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use proprely relative paths, in the case of your css, the path should be ./css/bootstrap.css , ./css/shop.css etcc same thing for your js

Notice that your page is looking for the css at the root directory, while it is actually under /DuAn